# How can I resolve this type error in my project blogpost object not iterable?

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py.
I suspect that i need to create a another model to handle entries. But which i think will not neccesary.

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from . models import BlogPost

    def index(request):
       return render(request, 'blogs/index.html')

    def posts(request):
    '''displays all blogs'''
    all_posts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {
    'posts': all_posts
       }
    return render(request, 'blogs/all_posts.html', context)

    def post (request, posts_id):
    single_post = BlogPost.objects.get(id = posts_id)
    context = {
    'single_post':single_post
    }
    return render(request, 'blogs/post.html', context)
```

This is my html file

```
    {% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

    {% block body %}
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    {% for posts in single_post %}
    <h3>{{posts.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{posts.text}}</p>
    <p>{{posts.date_added}}</p>

    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock body %}
```

and this is my urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    app_name = 'blogs'

    urlpatterns = [
    path('all_posts/<int:posts_id>/', views.post, name = 'post'),
    path('all_posts/', views.posts, name = 'all_posts'),
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
```

Here is my model definition for the project. The various fields have be defined correctly

```
    from django.db import models

    class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title}'

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Blog_Post'
    managed = True
    verbose_name = 'BlogPost'
    verbose_name_plural = 'BlogPosts'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't iterate object in Django

as **get** method return a single object not queryset

try this

```
 {% extends "blogs/base.html" %}
 {% block body %}
 <h1>Posts</h1>
 
 <h3>{{single_post.title}}</h3>
 <p>{{single_post.text}}</p>
 <p>{{single_post.date_added}}</p>
 
 {% endfor %}
 {% endblock body %}
```

Read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

    {% block body %}
    <h1>Posts</h1>
     {% for single_post  in posts %}
       <h3>{{single_post.title}}</h3>
       <p>{{single_post.text}}</p>
       <p>{{single_post.date_added}}</p>

     {% endfor %}
    {% endblock body %}
```

Comment: @JUSTIN KPAKPA, Please have a look in the code.